# Using Dojo, how can I refresh a div dynamically?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using Dojo and Javascript to perform a simple function of:

- find a certain div with ID
- update that div style section

Below is the module that contains the code for the above intention. The resize function is called from the main module. The original div style is set at the main module: however, whenever a "resize" occurs, the main module would call this resize function to update with a different style.

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare',
'dojo/query',
'dojo/_base/html'
],
function(declare, query, html) {
  return declare([], {
    baseClass: 'jimu-panel jimu-bottom-panel',

    resize: function () {
      var someNode = query("#widgets_panel")
      if (someNode != null) {
        // found it
        this._setPosition(someNode);
      } else {
        console.error ("Cannot find the node");
      };
    },

    _setPosition: function (somenode) {
      // set the style
      // refresh the node
      html.setStyle (somenode, "left", "10px");
      html.setStyle (somenode, "right", "auto");
      html.setStyle (somenode, "bottom", "20px");
      html.setStyle (somenode, "top", "auto");
      html.setStyle (somenode, "position", "absolute");
      somenode.refresh();
    }
  });
});
```

1. When I run the program via the browser, console error saying that refresh() is not a function. However, the div was refresh with correct style setting.
2. If I remove the node.refresh() statement, the div is NOT refresh and display with incorrect style. Of course no error.

I'd researched this topic and found some examples of using refresh(), update() with a DOM node but not within the Dojo context. Is there a way to refresh a DOM node dynamically without error?

Thanks,

Chi

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `refresh` neither `update`.
Instead use `dojo/dom-style` as the following:

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare',
'dojo/query',
'dojo/dom-style'
],
function(declare, query, domStyle) {
  return declare([], {
    baseClass: 'jimu-panel jimu-bottom-panel',

    resize: function () {
      var someNode = query("#widgets_panel")
      if (someNode != null) {
        // found it
        this._setPosition(someNode);
      } else {
        console.error ("Cannot find the node");
      };
    },

    _setPosition: function (somenode) {
      // set the style
      // refresh the node
      domStyle.set(somenode, {
          left: '10px',
          right: 'auto',
          bottom: '20px',
          top: 'auto',
          position: 'absolute'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

An even better approach would be to toggle a classname instead of playing with inline styles:

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare',
'dojo/query',
'dojo/dom-class'
],
function(declare, query, domClass) {
  return declare([], {
    baseClass: 'jimu-panel jimu-bottom-panel',

    resize: function () {
      var someNode = query("#widgets_panel")
      if (someNode != null) {
        // found it
        this._setPosition(someNode);
      } else {
        console.error ("Cannot find the node");
      };
    },

    _setPosition: function (somenode) {
      // set the style
      // refresh the node
      domClass.add(somenode, 'newDivStyle');
    }
  });
});
```

In the CSS file, you create the corresponding class:

```
.newDivStyle {
      left: 10px;
      right: auto;
      bottom: 20px;
      top: auto;
      position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. I just try the first method and it has the same effect as my original code (**no** update of intended style.) When I add the refresh back in, it is working as expected (with new style.) For the second method, it adds the new class but somehow showing the original style (I suspect it has been written over later) so it does not work as intended.  --Chi

Comment: with refresh it works because of the JS error. It stops the execution of the next instructions. So my bet is: something else is changing the style right after the `_setPosition`. You should see what runs next. The problem you describe with 2nd method tends to confirm my bet.

Comment: Hi Ben. The main module will change the style afterward back to the default value if the style has not been changed effectively in my module. The developer had explained that for some reason the JS error had caused the style to be effective so it was not modified again afterward by the main module. I prefer to invoke the right function to effective the change than by chance with the JS error.